# Need to access elements of a admin server browser

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am new to watir and below is my query:

Through browser, I have connected to the linux server, and I am able to automate this process.

Now after logging in, the browser opens a admin page (Webtop), I need to access the elements of that admin page, but I cannot. Also, even a simple `browser.text.include? "suplaonk"` is not giving the output, the same with `browser.title`.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what webtop is but as per this link webtop pages are defined in PSML  (Portal Standard Markup Language) i.e. not html. So, I dont think watir would be the best choice for what you are trying to do. If you think the page is actually HTML can you post the html using the firebug? 
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v8r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.netcool_wt.doc%2Fag%2FxF11248784180104.html

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<frameset id="MainFrame" frameborder="NO" framespacing="0" border="0" cols="*" rows="110,*,17">
</html>

Comment: I guess firewall is blocking to access the elements of that page.
How to overcome this? I tried by disabling the firewall but of no use.

Comment: This link might be the answer. http://watirmelon.com/2012/06/27/automatic-firefox-authentication-when-using-selenium-webdriver-with-autoauth/